# runOnUiThread is not running in AsyncTask

Tags: android, multithreading

I'm coding a program which **fetches the data from MySql from server (using JSON)** and it  **updates the UI** accordingly,

I'm fetching two types of data using **AsyncTask** from Server

```
1) Bubble Answers
2) Comments
```

The parseBubbleAnswers method successfully runs and Updates UI,
but parseComments class which is AsyncTask, and which call parseComments method in doInBackground, is not running `runOnUiThread(new Runnable() { run() });`

Can anyone help me in solving this

Here is my code :

```
public class FetchServer extends Activity
{
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        String photoId = "1"; // photo id for which the data is fetched
        checkBubbleData(photoId); // which call AsyncTask - 2 differnt calls
    }
    public void checkBubbleData(String photoId)
    {
        new parseBubbleAnswers().execute(photoId); // to fetch bubble answers
        new parseComments().execute(photoId); // to fetch comments
    }
    class parseBubbleAnswers extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,String> 
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Looper.prepare();
            parseBubbleAnswers(); // which has runOnUiThread(new Runnable() which updates (successfully !) the UI
            return null;
        }
    }
    class parseComments extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,String> 
    {

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) 
        {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Looper.prepare();

            String parseComReturn = parseComments();
            if(parseComReturn=="end")
            {
                commentBuilder(); // which will update UI after fetch data by parseComments() method
            }
        }
    }
    public void commentBuilder()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // while debugging, it comes here, on Step Over it stick for 2 times and then move at the end of method without error 
        {       
            public void run() 
            {
                // update UI code
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: check the solution I have posted below. Let me know if there is still issue with that. THanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Try this way :**

First create one `Handler` :

```
Handler mHandler = new Handler();
```

**Change this,**

```
public void commentBuilder()
    {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() // while debugging, it comes here, on Step Over it stick for 2 times and then move at the end of method without error 
        {       
            public void run() 
            {
                // update UI code
            }
        });
    }
```

**With,**

```
public void commentBuilder()
    {
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                while (isRunning) {
                    try {
                       // Thread.sleep(10000);
                        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                                // Write your code here to update the UI.                               
                            }
                        });
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        // TODO: handle exception
                    }
                }
            }
        }).start();
    }
```

Stop thread by this once you are done with UI,

```
isRunning = false;
```

**EDIT :**

Try to Use Async Task in this way :

```
class parseComments extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,String> 
    {
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            String parseComReturn = parseComments();
            return parseComReturn;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            if(result.equals("end"))
            {
                commentBuilder();
            }
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: i used this one, i m also debugging the code, when debugger comes to  }).start(); this line, it goes at the end of the method without any error, it suppose to go inside run(), but is not executing run(), why ?

Comment: @SunilLohar have you declared `boolean isRunning = true;` at top of application? Because it is working fine for me.

Comment: no its not working for me, i have declared boolean isRunning = true; but main problem is , it is not going inside run(), after start(), it excutes return statement in AsyncTask from which the method is called.

Comment: it is saying in debugger Thread [<13> AsycnTask #2](Suspended)

Comment: @SunilLohar see the edited answer I have posted and for test just stop `parseBubbleAnswers taks` and run only this task with this changes.

Comment: thanks , now it is going inside first run(), but it doent go inside mHandler.post(new Runnable() {,

Comment: @SunilLohar okay. now can you try again with your original `runOnUiThread` instead of `mHandler`?

Answer (score 8):

`runOnUiThread` is a method of `Activity`, `AsyncTask` has no reference to Activity.

however, AsyncTask already runs on the UI thread and was designed to do exactly that.

just deal with the UI changes in `onPostExecute`.

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String result) {} method is not executed

Comment: you need to return it's executed after `doInBackground` is finished, try overriding it and logging to see if it's called

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar issue.

Just pass the reference of the Activity class to the parseComments class.

```
class parseComments extends AsyncTask<String, Integer,String>{

 Activity activity;
 public parseComments(Activity activity){
  this.activity = activity;
 }
}
```

After that you can use runOnUiThread as

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
  @Override
  public void run(){

  }
});
```

It will only work with Activity class. Not Context class.