# I want to run an AsyncTask on UI thread - how can I do that?

Tags: android

I have a specific case where I want to run an AsyncTask's doInBackground on UI Thread. How can I do that?

Comment: Async tasks are designed to avoid running some tasks independent of UI thread, such as network calls. They run on their own thread.

Comment: what kind of special case it is? Do you want to update any UI widget?

Comment: you can perform UI actions on pre,post,onprogress of async task !

Comment: The entire point of an `AsyncTask` is for `doInBackground` to *not* run on the UI thread.  If you want to run something on the UI thread, just call it directly.

Comment: I want to run it on the UI thread on tablets only :) isnt there a way?

Comment: Hey guy, the problem is you are asking God to build a stone which He can't carry

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You definitively could, but as @Devrath said, it is pointless. AsyncTask are used for background operation.

Here is a sample that uses the runOnUiThread method:

```
private class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // WORK on UI thread here
            }
        });
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {}

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
}
```

Comment: I think this is the correct answer, although I ended up working around it in another way

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing the following:

Got all the code from doInBackground and moved it to a method.

In doInBackground I make a call only to this method.

In the cases where I need the asynctask to be executed normally, I call LongOperation().execute()

In the cases where I need the asynctask to be ran on the UI thread, I dont call it but I call the method instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public void commentBuilder() {
new Thread(new Runnable() {
@Override
public void run() {
//Your code 
}
}).start();
}
```

Also, see this for more detail https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038370

Answer (score 0):

***As far i know ..... You cannot !***

- [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) are designed to perform `background task` which takes
  longer time to perform
- So they have to be performed in a seperate thread different from the
  mainthread
- `Mainthread` takes care of all the UI for your app

---

**If you want ot update a UI while performing a background operation**::

- Just use `onProgressUpdate` method of the `AsyncTask` to update the
  UI during the background operation
- else use `onPre` method to update UI before the `beckground` call is
  made
- Else finally use `onPost` method to update after rte `async task`
  completes `doInBackground`

---

### {SAMPLE}

```
private class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        Thread.interrupted();
                    }
                }
                return "Executed";
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.output);
                txt.setText("Executed"); // txt.setText(result);
                // might want to change "executed" for the returned string passed
                // into onPostExecute() but that is upto you
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {}

            @Override
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {}
        }
```